# Subtracting min value from previous value in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to subtract the minimum value of a column in a DataFrame from the value just above it. In `R` I would do this:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=c(5,6,7,4,9))
df
  a b
1 1 5
2 2 6
3 3 7
4 4 4
5 5 9
df$b[which.min(df$b)-1] - df$b[which.min(df$b)]
[1] 3
```

How can I do the same thing in `pandas`? More generally, how can I extract the row number in a `pandas` DataFrame where a certain condition is met?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `argmin` to find out the index of the minimum value(the first one if there are ties), then you can do the subtraction based on the location:

```
index = df.b.argmin()
df.b[index-1] - df.b[index]
# 3
```

In case the index is not consecutive numbers:

```
i_index = df.b.values.argmin()
df.b.iat[i_index-1] - df.b.iat[i_index]
# 3
```

Or less efficiently:

```
-df.b.diff()[df.b.argmin()]
# 3.0
```

Comment: You can also use `pandas.DataFrame.idxmin()` Any idea which one would is better?

Comment: @CharlesMorris Right. Not an official answer, but I don't expect a big difference between `idxmin` and `argmin` performance side.

Comment: @CharlesMorris `argmin` is specifically an `Index` method, `idxmin` is available to `Series`, `DataFrame`s and `groupby` objects

Comment: @EdChum Does that mean that `idxmin` is more versatile, or just has a different use case?

Comment: There just different methods that achieve the same result, it probably just sounds weird to have `idxmin` on an `Index` object as it could be confused with `min`, conversely `argmin` on a `Series` could be confused with `min`, whilst `idxmin` should be more understandable. Additionally `idxmin` has `skipna` arg, `argmin` doesn't for some reason